# When running the project I'm getting error: Warning: opendir failed to open dir: not implemented

Tags: php

In `index.php` I have this code:

```
<?php
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$) |(\.Gif$)"; //valid image extensions 
$files = array(); 
$curimage=0; 
if($handle = opendir("http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files")) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
        if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
            //Output it as a JavaScript array element 
            $files[] = $file; 
            $curimage++; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
} 
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    #Timer_Countdown{
    background:black;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
  </style>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

$json = json_encode($files);
//json = <?php echo $json; ?>
var images = JSON.parse(json);
//var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;
//var images = [];
var x = -1; 
var swap_hours = 0;
var swap_minutes = 0;
var swap_seconds = 5;

var down_counter_hours;
var down_counter_minutes;
var down_counter_seconds;

function initTimer() {

    down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
    down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
    down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    counter = setInterval(switcher, 1000);
}

function restartCounter() {
        down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
        down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
        down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
}

function switcher() {
    down_counter_seconds--;
    if (down_counter_hours <= 0 && down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_seconds <= 0) {
        swapColor();
        restartCounter();
    }
    if (down_counter_seconds <= 0 && down_counter_minutes > 0) {
        down_counter_seconds = 60;
        down_counter_minutes--;
    }
    if (down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_hours > 0) {
        down_counter_minutes = 60;
        down_counter_hours--;
    }

    document.getElementById("Timer_Countdown").innerText =        down_counter_hours+":"+down_counter_minutes+":"+down_counter_seconds;
}

function swapColor() {
    displayNextImage();
}

      </script>
      <div id="div_hours" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_minutes" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_seconds" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_switcher" class="div_box"></div>
   </head>

   <body onload = "initTimer()">
       <div id="Timer_Countdown">&nbsp;</div>
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage(); restartCounter()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage(); restartCounter()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

My host website is ipage.com
In the filemanager on ipage.com i see the directory files/radar-simulation-files from the root directory.

I'm using netbeans 8.0.1 and xampp to run localhost apache server.

In NetBeans when I click the run button it's going to this location:

```
http://localhost/PhpProject2/index.php
```

And there, above the first image I see:

> Warning: opendir(http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files): failed to open dir: not implemented in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\index.php on line 5

What I want to do is to get a list of all images in the directory files/radar-simulation-files

EDIT

This is the code i tried now:

```
<?php
$username = 'my domain name';
$password = 'my pass';
$basepath = 'domains/newsxpressmedia.com/public_html/';
$handle = opendir("ftp://{$username}:{$password}@ftp.ipage.com/{$basepath}files/radar-simulation-files");
//$imgdir = 'images/'; //Pick your folder
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif'); //Allowed types of files
//$dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Open directory
while($imgfile = \readdir(handle))
{
  if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
      in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
/*If the file is an image add it to the array*/
  {$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
}
echo "<ul>";

 $totimg = count($a_img);  //The total count of all the images
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>";}
echo "</ul>";
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    #Timer_Countdown{
    background:black;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
  </style>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

/* @var $ar type */
var images = <?php echo \json_encode($imgfile) ?>;
//$json = json_encode($imgfile);
//json = <?php echo $json; ?>
//var images = JSON.parse(json);
//var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;
//var images = [];
var x = -1; 
var swap_hours = 0;
var swap_minutes = 0;
var swap_seconds = 5;

var down_counter_hours;
var down_counter_minutes;
var down_counter_seconds;

function initTimer() {

    down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
    down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
    down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    counter = setInterval(switcher, 1000);
}

function restartCounter() {
        down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
        down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
        down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
}

function switcher() {
    down_counter_seconds--;
    if (down_counter_hours <= 0 && down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_seconds <= 0) {
        swapColor();
        restartCounter();
    }
    if (down_counter_seconds <= 0 && down_counter_minutes > 0) {
        down_counter_seconds = 60;
        down_counter_minutes--;
    }
    if (down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_hours > 0) {
        down_counter_minutes = 60;
        down_counter_hours--;
    }

    document.getElementById("Timer_Countdown").innerText =        down_counter_hours+":"+down_counter_minutes+":"+down_counter_seconds;
}

function swapColor() {
    displayNextImage();
}

      </script>
      <div id="div_hours" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_minutes" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_seconds" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_switcher" class="div_box"></div>
   </head>

   <body onload = "initTimer()">
       <div id="Timer_Countdown">&nbsp;</div>
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage(); restartCounter()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage(); restartCounter()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have uploaded the file to my host domain ipage.com filemanager
I'm then browsing to:

[My site](http://newsxpressmedia.com/index1.php)

It start counting back the timer but then stop on 1

Then i'm doing on the website: Inspect element
And in the console i see error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

On line 23

Something is wrong with the php code that should get all the images files and put them in the array.

Comment: Edited my question now with what i tried now and what i'm getting what error i'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) to browse files over http. Instead you should try ftp connection, like:

```
$username = 'ftp-username';
$password = 'ftp-password';
$basepath = 'domains/newsxpressmedia.com/public_html/';
$handle = opendir("ftp://{$username}:{$password}@ftp.ipage.com/{$basepath}files/radar-simulation-files")
```